# Processing 3.4 - Diffusive shading vertices on water simulation

Tags: java, processing, vertex-shader

I just recently made this code that simulates the flow of water in the ocean:

```
// Global variables
int cols,rows;
int scl = 15;

int w = 3800;
int h = 1600;

float flying = 0;

float[][] terrain;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  cols = w / scl;
  rows = h / scl;
  terrain = new float[cols][rows];
}

void draw() {

  fill(255, 255, 255);

  flying -= 0.01;

  float yoff = flying;
  for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    float xoff = 0;
      for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
        terrain[x][y] = map(noise(xoff,yoff), 0, 1, -50, 50);
      xoff += 0.05;
  }
  yoff += 0.05;
 }

  background(0);

  stroke(255);

  translate(width/2, height/2+50);
  rotateX(PI/3);
  translate(-w/2,-h/2);
  for (int y = 0; y < rows-1; y++) {
     beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);

  for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {

   vertex(x*scl, y*scl, terrain[x][y]);
   vertex(x*scl, (y+1)*scl, terrain[x][y+1]);
 // rect(x*scl, y*scl, scl, scl);  
    }
    endShape();
  }
}
```

However, as you can see it is not shaded, just plain white. I have no clue how to shade it, I've looked everywhere but I don't know how to translate it into my code.

Would anyone be able to help by explaining how to do it or modify my code to add shaders? (it doesn't have to be glossy, diffusive is fine)

Any form of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So by "shading" do you mean a vertex shader?  You can use a Java library like LWJGL to access OpenGL shaders.  http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/GLSL_Shaders_with_LWJGL.html

Answer (score 1):

General "how do I do this" type questions are pretty hard to answer, as there isn't just one way to accomplish a particular goal. I'd recommend you start by googling "Processing shader" or checking in the Processing [reference](https://processing.org/reference/). You could also check the examples that come with Processing (go to File -> Examples) to see code samples that use shaders.

But I'll also point out that you don't really need shaders for this. You could just use the standard `fill()` function. Here's a simple example:

```
for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {

  fill(0, 100 + terrain[x][y], 200 + terrain[x][y]);

  vertex(x*scl, y*scl, terrain[x][y]);
  vertex(x*scl, (y+1)*scl, terrain[x][y+1]);
}
```

Here I'm using your `terrain` array to decide the color, but that's just the first thing I tried. I'm sure there are a ton of other ways to approach this.

[image: water simulation]